# Umbraco Routing or Model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, routes, url-routing, umbraco8

Having trouble in returning to view by passing model along with this.

errorMessage Cannot bind source type eCaptis.Models.Patient to model type Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.IPublishedContent.

```
public class PatientController : SurfaceController
{


    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Find(id);
        if (patient == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView( patient);
    }
}
```

I possibly suspect there is a problem with the routing, as after installing Umbraco v8, Debugger is not hitting RouteConfig.cs

Bit of BackGround: I have created a document type in Umbraco called home which has a child item edit and login

The home page will display a table whereby clicking on name it should navigate to edit patient view, so I have passed the Id of the patient to the controller upon clicking the name of a patient as shown in the code above.

Doing this my URL is changing from http://localhost:12345 to http://localhost:12345/umbraco/Surface/Patient/Edit/345

In general, if we don't use surface controller or Umbraco this URL could be like http://localhost:12345 to http://localhost:12345/Patient/Edit/345

I have even looked into route hijacking but this did not help me or maybe because of my lack of understanding.

Any help in fixing this is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco requires SurfaceController names to be appended with "SurfaceController" for things to work: https://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/developer/fundamentals/surface-controllers/the-surface-controller/documentation

So hopefully it's as easy as renaming your controller to PatientSurfaceController?